# Add class depending on JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

With dynamically generated HTML from JSON data I'm trying to add a class to each `.status-card`, in this case depending on the value of `c.callStatus`. This is the closest I got, but this just adds `active` class to all `status-card`. I'm guessing it's something to do with how I'm using `$(this)` or I'm missing something else?

```
$(function() {
    var agents = [];
    $.getJSON('js/agents.json', function(a) {
        $.each(a.agents, function(b, c) {
            var content = 
            '<div class="status-card">' +
            '<div class="agent-details">' +
            '<span class="agent-name">' + c.name + '</span>' +
            '<span class="handling-state">' + c.callStatus + '</span>' +
            '<span class="handling-time">' + c.handlingTime + '</span>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="status-indicator"></div>' +
            '</div>'
            $(content).appendTo('#left');

            //Add class depending on callStatus
            $('.status-card').each(function() {
              if (c.callStatus == 'On Call') {
                $(this).removeClass('idle away').addClass('active');
              } else if (c.callStatus == 'Idle') {
                $(this).removeClass('active away').addClass('idle');
              } else {
                $(this).removeClass('active idle').addClass('away');
              }
              console.log(c.callStatus);
            });
        });

    });

});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you also add sample `json` response to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `$('.status-card').each()` for each `agent` in your `a.agents` list. so in the final iterate all `.status-card` elements will have the last `agent.callStatus` evaluated class.

I'd write something like this.

```
$(function() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  function createStatusCard(name,callStatus,handlingTime) {                                                                                                                                                                                    
    var status_class_map = {                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      "On Call" : "active",                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      "Idle" : "idle"                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    };                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    var $content = $("<div/>").addClass("status-card").addClass(function(){                                                                                                                                                                    
      return status_class_map[callStatus] || "away";                                                                                                                                                                                           
    });                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    $content.html('<div class="agent-details">' +                                                                                                                                                                                              
      '<span class="agent-name">' + name + '</span>' +                                                                                                                                                                                         
      '<span class="handling-state">' + callStatus + '</span>' +                                                                                                                                                                               
      '<span class="handling-time">' + handlingTime + '</span>' +                                                                                                                                                                              
      '</div>' +                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      '<div class="status-indicator"></div>');                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    return $content;                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  $.getJSON('agents.json', function(a) {                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    $.each(a.agents, function(b, c) {                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      $("#left").append(createStatusCard(c.name,c.callStatus,c.handlingTime));                                                                                                                                                                 
    });                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  });                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
});
```

it's more readable and easier to debug.

Answer (score 2):

> This is the closest I got, but this just adds `active` class to all `status-card`.

This is happening because after adding each `status-card` you are adding other classes to all the status cards added till now:

```
$.each(a.agents, function(b, c) {
 ....
    // here you are updating the class for all the cards added till now.
    $('.status-card').each(function() {
     ....
    });
 ....
});
```

So, the `active` classes is added to all the other cards because that might be the `callStatus` in the last outer loop.

You can compute the `className` based on the `callStatus` before creating the HTML and then use that `className` in  HTML like this:

```
function getClassNameByStatus (callStatus) {
    switch(callStatus){
        case "On Call":
            return "active";
        case "Idle":
            return "idle";
        default:
            return "away";
    }
}

$.each(a.agents, function(b, c) {
    var className = getClassNameByStatus(c.callStatus);
    var content =
        '<div class="status-card' + className + '">' +
        ....; // rest of the HTML
    $(content).appendTo('#left');
});
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the explanation much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have your `status-card` `each` loop nested inside your JSON loop. Therefore every time you loop through an object from the JSON data you are setting all of the `status-card` element's class which have already been added to the DOM.

You could restructure to set the class as you build the elements before appending.

```
    $.each(a.agents, function(b, c) {
        var content = 
        '<div class="agent-details">' +
        '<span class="agent-name">' + c.name + '</span>' +
        '<span class="handling-state">' + c.callStatus + '</span>' +
        '<span class="handling-time">' + c.handlingTime + '</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="status-indicator"></div>';

        var $statusCard = $("<div/>").addClass("status-card");
                                     .append(content);

        $statusCard.addClass(function(){
             switch(c.callStatus){
                case "On Call":
                   return "active";
                case "Idle":
                   return "idle";
                default:
                   return "away";
             }
        }());

        $statusCard.appendTo('#left');


    });
```